# Spans in $V$ giving spans in $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a $k$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for two bases $\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ and $\{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $V = \operatorname{span}(b_1, \dots, b_k) = \operatorname{span}(u_1, \dots, u_k)$. So $b_i = \sum_{j=1}^k v_i^ju_j$. Can we write $\beta_i = \sum_{j=1}^k v^j_i \gamma_j$ with the same coefficients if $\{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n\}$ and $\{\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n\}$ are the corresponding dual bases? I.e. is $V^* =\operatorname{span}(\beta_1, \dots, \beta_k) = \operatorname{span}(\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_k)$?

Hi everyone! I am trying to prove this result, and I think that this result should be true, but I don't have a way to prove it. If $$b_i = \sum_{j=1}^k v_i^ju_j$$ then $$\delta_{\ell i}=\beta_\ell(b_i) = \sum_{j=1}^k v^j_i  \beta_\ell (u_j)$$ and

$$\gamma_\ell(b_i) = \sum_{j=1}^k v^j_i  \gamma_\ell (u_j) = \sum_{j=1}^k v_i^j \delta_{\ell i}$$

but neither of these gives the correct result yet.

Comment: Have you tried $v^i_j$?

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn’t hold. The point of the exercise is to illustrate that each dual basis vector depends on all basis vectors, it’s not determined by  its “partner” – in fact, that’s the only basis vector its direction *doesn’t* depend on.

You can see this already in two dimensions: Let $\{b_1,b_2\}$ be the canonical basis, and let $u_1=b_1$ but $u_2\not\parallel b_2$. The hypotheses are satisfied for $k=1$, but $\beta_1$ can’t be expressed in terms of $\gamma_1$ (since $\langle\beta_1,b_2\rangle=0$ and $\langle\gamma_1,u_2\rangle=0$ but $u_2\not\parallel b_2$, so $\gamma_1\parallel\beta_1$ would imply $\beta_1=\gamma_1=0$).

It’s often worthwhile to think of the smallest possible examples before you try to prove something in abstract generality that you don’t have intuition for yet (in fact thinking about such examples is often what lets you acquire intuition about the general statements).